# Ipad Simulator not auto rotating

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, orientation, ios-simulator

I have an an iphone app and am using `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` to determine when to autorotate. On the iphone, I specify that `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` is the only allowed orientation; On the iPad, I just return YES (ie all allowed), like so:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) //also tried using [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] to no avail
  return YES; //doesn't get here
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

This is in every view controller of the tab bar. When I NSLog() the `[[UIDevice currentDevice]   userInterfaceIdiom]`, it returns 0 (or `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone`).

Does the iPad simulator always return `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM work with Targeted Device Family](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167740/does-ui-user-interface-idiom-work-with-targeted-device-family)

Comment: Here is my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565693/xcode-4-5-ios-6-0-simulator-orientation-not-working/12568678#12568678

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your answer is here: [Does UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM work with Targeted Device Family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167740/does-ui-user-interface-idiom-work-with-targeted-device-family)

Comment: Thanks for the link - several searches didn't find it.